# How can I create RTL files in the makfile?

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, makefile

I have a huge makefile for a current project.For better understanding I'd like to create a call graph with egypt. Therefore the RTL Files are needed. For a smaller project I've created them by my self with

```
gcc main.c -fdump-rtl-expand
gcc foo.c -fdump-rtl-expand
...
```

but for this bigger project it would be nice if that could be achieved with the makefile. Is there a way I could add it to the makefile with a CFLAG as example?

The egypt workflow can be seen on this [site](https://lihashgnis.blogspot.ch/2016/05/generating-call-graph-of-c-code-linux.html)

Comment: Your example does not contain the rules for building that object files.

Comment: Please first narrow down your code to a smaller example that reproduces the problem.  Especially, if you make it so it has normal-length lines, which don't have to be horizontally scrolled, that would be helpful.

Comment: To huge example was just to demonstrate the size of the project. The question itself could be written as one liner too I guess: Where and what do I have to add to a makfile to get RTL expands of each .c file? That could maybe be answered in general.

Comment: Hello, do you solve it now?